# Shared string between Service and MainActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have a service and the main activity. Is there any way I can share a String in particular between these two. I have a method in the MainActivity that has to be executed only after the String from the service arrives. Is there any way of doing the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will allow your `Service` to publish a `String` to your `Activity`. If you need to send data in the other direction use a more casual approach such as `startService(Intent)`.

Setup a local `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity`:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!MyService.ACTION_NEW_STRING.equals(intent.getAction()) return;

    String myString = intent.getStringExtra(MyService.EXTRA_STRING);
    // do whatever you need to do here
  }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.ACTION_NEW_STRING));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

In your `Service` declare needed constants:

```
public static final String ACTION_NEW_STRING = "your_application_id.ACTION_NEW_STRING";
// or BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".ACTION_NEW_STRING" in Android Studio

public static final String EXTRA_STRING = "EXTRA_STRING";

private LocalBroadcastManager mManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  mManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
}
```

In your service once you have your new `String`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_NEW_STRING);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING, myString);
mManager.sendBroadcast(i);
```

More reading on this topic: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. One small doubt, what method am I supposed to call? I am 15 years old so sorry for the noob question.

Comment: The service does its work usually in `onStartCommand(...)`. Once the service has done its work and you have the string you need to send to `MainActivity` write the third piece of code.